# Tesseract Android Java. Ошибка подключения языка

Tags: java, android, распознавание-символов, tesseract

За основу беру эту статью.
http://www.codepool.biz/making-an-android-ocr-application-with-tesseract.html

С английским языком проблем нет, но как только пытаюсь подключить любой другой язык приложение крашится.

Не может подключить языковой пакет. 
Как и в описании 
добавила язык в папку tessdata

```
package com.dynamsoft.tessocr;

import java.io.File;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

public class TessOCR {
    private TessBaseAPI mTess;

    public TessOCR() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mTess = new TessBaseAPI();
        String datapath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tesseract/";
        String language = "rus";
        File dir = new File(datapath + "tessdata/");
        if (!dir.exists()) 
            dir.mkdirs();
        mTess.init(datapath, language);
    }

    public String getOCRResult(Bitmap bitmap) {

        mTess.setImage(bitmap);
        String result = mTess.getUTF8Text();

        return result;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mTess != null)
            mTess.end();
    }

}
```

Также добавила язык в папку asset при сборке. Вылетает ошибка не может подключить язык. И не только русский, но и другие.

Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

танцуем. нашла другой языковой пакет другой версии и все заработало. в гитхабе ошибочная версия выложена!